# Disable queryResultCache for a single Solr query

Tags: caching, solr, solrcloud, solr-query-syntax, query-cache

Disclaimer: I'm a Solr newbie so I apologize in advance if this sounds lame.

I'm trying to optimize Solr queries running on an instance which has `queryResultCache` turned on. Caching restricts my ability to experiment with queries and analyze how much time each variation of the query takes.

1. I'm querying Solr via `curl`.
2. Disabling `queryResultCache` on this instance or acquiring a different instance is not an option.

Any help or ideas are welcome.

1. I [tried this approach](https://solr.apache.org/guide/7_3/common-query-parameters.html#cache-parameter) and passed `cache=false` as a `curl` parameter to the Solr query.
2. I don't believe it worked since query time was 26926 the first time and then its averaging ~ 152.

Comment: Can you show the query you are executing? to check if it is correctly formatted. Also, do you have cleaned (empty) the cache before doing the experiment?

Comment: No, I can't really post the query. I did not empty the cache prior to the experiment. Would that impact this functionality though?